# php regular expression for phone numbers with diffrent lenght and space or hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I need some help with a regular expression that will validate phone numbers like the following 3 examples:

```
054238852
054 238 852
054-238-852
```

The first two are validated by using this regular expression `/^\d+(\s\d+)*$/` for the third, I can't figure out how to modify the regular expression in order to work for all 3 exampels.

Thanks!

Comment: `^\d{3}([\s-]?)\d{3}\1\d{3}$` https://regex101.com/r/cT5zW6/1)

Comment: Searching SO for `phone number regex` gives 1361 hits. I'm sure several of them answers your question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj How about the top one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation. ;)

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks, I modified the expression to /^\d+([\s-]?\d+)*$/ .The limit for only 3 digits is not a must. Many thanks

Comment: @sorin your regex should validate this `231 232234` as True..